# on-the-fly parsing of binary serial data in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, stream, binary, pyserial

I'm new to using Python3 for data acquisition. I'm trying to find a way to parse binary data from a serial port on Linux.

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial(   
    port='/dev/ttyS0',
    baudrate = 9600,
    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
    timeout=1)
counter = 0

while 1:
    x = ser.read(31)
    print (x)
```

This gives me a string which I'm not sure about the format of:

```
x='\x00\x00\x91\x00\x02\x88BM\x00\x1c\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\xe1\x00K\x00\x1a\x00\x02\x00\x00'
```

using

```
x.encode('hex')
```

gives a string of hex values

```
x='000091000288**424d**001c00000001000100000001000100e1004b001a00020000'
```

where `0x42` is the end of message and `0x4d` is start of message.

I can convert it into a base 10 list using

```
y = map(ord,x)
print(y)
```

Then I have a way to re-order the message using the indexes but surely there is a neater way? How do I create a list which starts at `0x4d` to parse with?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using python3, this is likely already bytes:

```
x='\x00\x00\x91\x00\x02\x88BM\x00\x1c\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\xe1\x00K\x00\x1a\x00\x02\x00\x00'
```

It likely looks this way because Python printed it for you, and all of the non-ascii characters are shown in hex. Your start of message is in `0x42, 0x4d` which is `BM` in ascii and can be seen in the data above between `0x88` and `0x00` as `\x88BM\x00`.

I would suggest just iterating over the byte array in `x` to do your parsing.  The encoding and mapping should not be needed.

```
for b in x:
    if b == 0x4d:
        found_byte1 = True
    ...  # etc
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this first, if you look at the encoded hex string 0x4d is there but in the first print out it has been replaced with \x88BM, which I assume includes 0x88 but sum how merged 0x42 and 0x4d with BM.

Comment: `\x88BM` is three separate bytes.  0x88 (\x88), 0x42 (B) & 0x4d (M)

Comment: ok, that makes sense, so to go through in hex it would need encoding to hex first? How do you do that to get a hex list?

Comment: I do not think you need encode.  What `type` is the object returned by `ser.read()` ?